# How to combine information from a main table and a log table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-structures

I currently have 2 tables in my database that i need to combine information from.
One of them is a log table, that registers the status change of all products in the system. Structure example:

| ChangeDate | Product | LastStatus | NewStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | A | New | Aging |
| 2021-11-02 | A | Aging | Ressuply |
| 2021-11-25 | A | Ressuply | OFF |
| 2021-08-03 | B | New | Aging |
| 2021-09-04 | B | New | Aging |
| 2021-10-13 | B | Ressuply | OFF |

The other one is a fact table that contains each sale of each product.
Structure example:

| Date | Product | PricePaid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-02 | A | 124 |
| 2021-11-05 | A | 115 |
| 2021-08-25 | B | 223 |
| 2021-09-03 | B | 218 |

I want to write a statement that brings me the product's status at the time when it was sold.
Desired result:

| Date | Product | PricePaid | StatusAtTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-02 | A | 124 | Aging |
| 2021-11-05 | A | 115 | Ressuply |
| 2021-08-25 | B | 223 | Aging |
| 2021-09-03 | B | 218 | Aging |

I've been banging my head for about a week now, and can´t seem to find an answer to this. I´d guess the biggest challenge is performance, since the fact table has around 2M lines, and the log table is quite large as well.

Thank you guys in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
select top(1) with ties s.*, l.NewStatus
from sales s
join statusLog l on s.Product = l.Product and s.Date >= l.ChangeDate
order by row_number() over(partition by s.Product, s.Date order by l.ChangeDate desc);
```

With the sample data returns

```
Date    Product PricePaid   NewStatus
2021-10-02  A   124 Aging
2021-11-05  A   115 Ressuply
2021-08-25  B   223 Aging
2021-09-03  B   218 Aging
```

Comment: Hi Serg, i tried your answer but couldn´t get it to work. It will only return me 1 row, and it also has the wrong status :(

Comment: @BrunoMathias, .. Corrected it a bit.

Comment: worked like a charm this time. Thank you very much !! :)